# Azure Data Factory Error: "incorrect syntax near"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, incremental-load

I'm trying to do a simple incremental update from an on-prem database as source to Azure SQL database based on a varchar column called "RP" in On-Prem database that contains "date+staticdescription" for example: "20210314MetroFactory"

[image: On-Prem DB Columns Snapshot]

1- I've created a Lookup activity called Lookup1 using a table created in Azure SQL Database and uses this Query

"Select RP from SubsetwatermarkTable"

[image: Lookup Activity Snapshot]

2- I've created a Copy data activity where the source settings have this Query

"Select * from SourceDevSubsetTable WHERE RP NOT IN '@{activity('Lookup1').output.value}'"

[image: Copy Activity Snapshot]

When debugging -- I'm getting the error:

Failure type: User configuration issue

> Details: Failure happened on 'Source' side.
> 'Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near
> '[{"RP":"20210307_1Plant
> 1KAO"},{"RP":"20210314MetroFactory"},{"RP":"20210312MetroFactory"},{"RP":"20210312MetroFactory"},{"RP":"2'.,Source=.Net
> SqlClient Data
> Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect
> syntax near
> '[{"RP":"20210311MetroFactory"},{"RP":"20210311MetroFactory"},{"RP":"202103140MetroFactory"},{"RP":"20210308MetroFactory"},{"RP":"2'.,},],'

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it even if it requires creating more activities.

Note: There is no LastModifiedDate column in the table. Also I haven't yet created the StoredProcedure that will update the Lookup table when it is done with the incremental copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve is right as to why it is failling and the query you need in the Copy Data.

As he says, you want a comma-separated list of quoted values to use in your IN clause.

You can get this more easily though - from your Lookup directly using this query:-

```
select stuff(
  (
    select ','''+rp+''''
    from   subsetwatermarktable
    for    xml path('')
  )
  , 1, 1, ''
) as in_clause
```

The sub-query gets the comma separated list with quotes around each rp-value, but has a spurious comma at the start - the outer query with `stuff` removes this.

Now tick the First Row Only box on the Lookup and change your Copy Data source query to:

```
select *
from   SourceDevSubsetTable
where  rp not in (@{activity('lookup').output.firstRow.in_clause})
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` is an array like your error shows

> [{"RP":"20210307_1Plant
> 1KAO"},{"RP":"20210314MetroFactory"},{"RP":"20210312MetroFactory"},{"RP":"20210312MetroFactory"},{"RP":"2'.,Source=.Net
> SqlClient Data
> Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect
> syntax near
> '[{"RP":"20210311MetroFactory"},{"RP":"20210311MetroFactory"},{"RP":"202103140MetroFactory"},{"RP":"20210308MetroFactory"},{"RP":"2'.,},]

However, your SQL should be like this:`Select * from SourceDevSubsetTable WHERE RP NOT IN ('20210307_1Plant 1KAO','20210314MetroFactory',...)`.

To achieve this in ADF, you need to do something like this:

1. create three variables like the following screenshot:
   [image]
2. loop your result of `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` and append `'item().RP'` to arrayvalues:

expression:`@activity('Lookup1').output.value`
[image]

expression:`@concat(variables('apostrophe'),item().RP,variables('apostrophe'))`

[image]

3.cast arrayvalues to string and add parentheses by Set variable activity
expression:`@concat('(',join(variables('arrayvalues'),','),')')`

4.copy to your Azure SQL database
expression:`Select * from SourceDevSubsetTable WHERE RP NOT IN @{variables('stringvalues')}`

[image]