# Dynamic query in azure data factory based on array variable

Tags: azure-data-factory, dynamic-queries

I want to create a copy activity, with a dynamic query, based on an array variable, inside azure data factory, for example I only want to load the information of the IDs that are in the table A of the database X inside the table B in the Y database.

The code in the set variable activity associated to the variable ID_Variable would be:
Select distinct ID from tableA;

And I tried it like this in the copy activity:
Select * from tableB where ID in (@variables('ID_Variable'));

But it didn't work, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a Lookup activity to run this SQL `Select distinct ID from tableA` and then pass it's output to your variable ID_Variable? If no, can you provide screenshots of your pipeline and your ID_Variable sample data?

Answer (score 0):

This is because that IN clause needs a comma-separated list of quoted values such as`(1,2,3,4)`, but array value in ADF is [1,2,3,4]. So it didn't work.

You need to change array value to comma-separated values enclosed in parentheses.
The Easy way is to change your first SQL `Select distinct ID from tableA` to

```
select stuff(
  (
    select distinct ','''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), ID) +''''
    from   tableA
    for    xml path('')
  )
  , 1, 1, ''
) as in_clause
```

if it's possible. Otherwise you need to do this with extra activity in ADF.
You can refer to this [error called Incorrect Syntax near in Azure DataFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66626537/error-called-incorrect-syntax-near-in-azure-datafactory/66632306#66632306).