# Use list of results of a Lookup activity in a 'WHERE field IN list' condition in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

as the title states, in an Azure Data Factory pipeline I am trying to use the results of a Lookup activity in a WHERE condition of a query against Salesforce.

To be more detailed, the Lookup activity has the option 'Select only first row' NOT selected and it looks as follow:

`SELECT id FROM staging_table`

Then I am trying to pass the output to a Copy Data activity that runs a query against Salesforce using the output of the Lookup in a condition that looks like `WHERE Id IN @output`, however any kind of syntax I try for the activity output results in some errors, I only managed to get it working for the first result of the array.

Thank you for any help you may provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you will get this result like this `[{"id":1},{"id":2}]` when you don't check Select only first row option. However, you need this output `(1,2)` in your SQL `WHERE Id IN @output`. So you need to get the output of your Lookup activity `(1,2)` in your first SQL or extract from `[{"id":1},{"id":2}]`.

Here is a similar question about this, you can try the solution. [error called Incorrect Syntax near in Azure DataFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66626537/error-called-incorrect-syntax-near-in-azure-datafactory)